# Windows Phone - like facebook page and check if it is like

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I found many tutorials of how to connect to facebook by Windows Phone but everytime example was with sharing on wall something. But what if I want to create page and then in app I want to user to have possibility to like it and if user liked it then he can have some more features or unlock content or so. Is it possible? Can I find good tutorial for this? Thanks